# Displaying API data using FutureBuilder

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter-web

I want to fetch data from a complex json API and display the data in a Flutter future builder.

This is the sample if json

```
 {
    "hours": [
        {
            "time": "2021-03-23T00:00:00+00:00",
            "waveHeight": {
                "icon": 1.35,
                "meteo": 1.25,
                "noaa": 1.28,
                "sg": 1.25
            }
        },
{
            "time": "2021-03-23T00:00:00+00:00",
            "waveHeight": {
                "icon": 1.35,
                "meteo": 1.25,
                "noaa": 1.28,
                "sg": 1.25
            }
        },
    ],
}
```

This is the function that fetch the data from the API

```
Future getJsonData() async {
    String url2 =
        'https://api.stormglass.io/v2/weather/point?lat=5.9774&lng=80.4288&params=waveHeight&start=2021-03-23&end2021-03-24';
    
    String apiKey =
        '0242ac130002-248f8380-7a54-11eb-8302-0242ac130002';
    print('0');

    
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url2),
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: apiKey});

   
    final _extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

    List<Wave> _data = [];
    List<Wave> _fetchedData = [];

    _extractedData['hours'].forEach((value) {
      _fetchedData.add(Wave(
        time: value['time'],
        icon: value['icon'],
        meteo: value['meteo'],
        noaa: value['noaa'],
        sg: value['sg'],
      ));
    });

    _data = _fetchedData;

    print(_data);

    return _data;
  }
```

The data is printing in the console as below

```
/flutter ( 4879): [Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', Instance of 'Wave', In
```

Below is the futurebuilder

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("API"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getJsonData(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data[0]['time']);
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When i run the app, the following error shows

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#e19f8):
Class 'Wave' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Wave'
Tried calling: []("time")
```

The following is the wave class

```
class Wave {
  final String time;
  final double icon;
  final double meteo;
  final double noaa;
  final double sg;

  Wave({
    this.time,
    this.icon,
    this.meteo,
    this.noaa,
    this.sg,
  });

  factory Wave.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Wave(
        time: json['time'],
        icon: json['icon'],
        meteo: json['mateo'],
        noaa: json['noaa'],
        sg: json['sg']);
  }
}
```

I want to get the data and print it in  a flutter listview

Comment: try snapshot.data[0].time

Comment: return Text(snapshot.data[0].time); data[0] is not a Map it is a Wave class

Comment: Text(snapshot.data[0].time) displays Instance of 'Wave' in the console

Answer (score 0):

This is because the data you returned from your getJsonData is not a map but a model class you created "WAVE".

Basically to access your "time" you need to change the code:

```
return Text(snapshot.data[0]['time']);
```

To

```
return Text(snapshot.data[0].time);
```

Comment: Class 'List<Wave>' has no instance getter 'time'. this error shows

Comment: Can you print the value of snapshot.data[0] in the console?

Comment: snapshot.data[0] displays Type 'Wave' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Okay, so can you please edit your question & add the WAVE Class model too? Also, now try printing snapshot.data[0].time, lets see what it does

Comment: When I print the API data on console it shows Instance of 'Wave' but not the json

Comment: That is because when you parsed your data in the function "getJsonData" you converted your JSON data into the List of Wave model. That is why it is not longer JSON but an Instance of class WAVE. Moreover, this should have worked "snapshot.data[0].time" .